# Le mot « equable » en français

Tags: vocabulaire

Le mot « equable » existe-t-il en français ? Ou bien un mot voisin ?

Je me demande puisque le mot anglais vient du latin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mais si qu'il existe.
Bon... enfin... on l'a eu utilisé en français quoi :

*Vaillance (car cette vertu est bien plus proprement dicte ainsi que la force) est une droite & forte asseurance, **equable** & uniforme de l'âme à l'encontre tous accidens dangereux*

(in *De la sagesse* par Pierre Charron 1777)

Montaigne lui fait aussi honneur dans ses essais :

*... mille femmelettes ont vescu au village une vie plus **equable**, plus doulce et plus constante que ne feut la sienne.*

Je ne saurais dire néanmoins quand il est sorti d'usage.

Nota : Il est bien évidemment attesté dans le Godefroy (dans ce même sens) qui observe que l'on écrit aussi *E**g**able*

Answer (score 1):

Un mot voisin par la racine et à la fois exact pour le traduire existe bien, c'est « égal ». Il est utilisé comme en anglais pour le climat et le tempérament humain.

expression pour le tempérament : être de tempérament égal (il est possible que cette expression ne soit pas utilisable pour le climat)

Ces gens sont de tempérament égal.

Le Gulf Stream donne à cette région un climat égal.

Comment: C'est bizarre qu'equable existe en anglais et pas en français, non ?

Comment: @Dimitris Vous voulez dire la même forme alors; non ce n'est pas du tout bizarre; vous semblez croire qu'il y aurait un système parfait d'introduction des termes dans les les deux langues! Il n'y jamais eu de  système de cette sorte; les auteurs des deux nations ont toujours choisi leur nouveaux termes selon ce qu'ils avaient à leur disposition et selon leur fantaisie; il était un temps où les apports dans l'anglais à partir du français étaient massifs, alors que les apports dans le sens inverse étaient nuls; de nos jours on assiste au phénomène inverse : la langue française (continué)

Comment: @Dimitris  se charge de vocabulaire anglais, mais de nature essentiellement anglo-saxonne (pas toujours souhaité d'ailleurs, franglais) alors que la langue anglaise n'emprunte pas énormément de vocabulaire français. Ces tendances sont liées à la puissance globale des nations et de nos jours ce facteur n'est plus associé avec le royaume unis mais beaucoup plus avec les EUA (mais il me semble que vous savez tout ça).